# Permission error in session declarations (PHP5)

Tags: permission-denied, php

I recently changed the root password (SSH), and now PHP's sessions don't work properly.
I did not change the path of the sessions, I know that for a fact.

Here's the error I'm receiving:

> Warning: Unknown: open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_utto82hjqi9mk4d1hdoahbgf80, O_RDWR)                                                      failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session) in Unknown on line 0

Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: Why are you using the root account for this...

Comment: Check for permissions on file and/or folder.

Comment: Your problem may be that the user account that apache runs as doesn't have permissions to write session data to /tmp (which is configures as sessions.save_path=/tmp in php.ini). 

So, either you need to give proper permissions to the /tmp dir (chmod 777) or change the session.save_path to a directory where the apache user has access.

Answer (score 0):

Change the permission of the folders, so that the user (which runs the page, e.g. www-data) can write there. You should Google for `chmod` and `chown`

Comment: That's `chmod` ;-) not `chomod`.